# Screen Won't Open When Drawing Checker Board Using Turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to draw a checker board using the Turtle library and am running into an error where the board window does not open. It was working at the beginning of my session about 30 minutes ago but, I changed  some stuff and want to know why it changed.

Here is my code:

```
##This program draws a checkboard using the turtle library
import turtle  

#below initiates the turtle pen and screen
penMain = turtle.Turtle()   
turtleMain = turtle.Screen() 
   
def turtleBoard(): 
   
    for x in range(4): 
        penMain.forward(30) 
        penMain.left(90) 
   
    penMain.forward(30)  
    turtleMain.setup(600, 600) 
    penMain.speed(50) 
        
    for a in range(8): 
        penMain.up()  
        penMain.setpos(0, 30 * a) 
        penMain.down() 
        for x in range(8): 
            if (a + x)% 2 == 0: 
                squareColor = 'black'
            else: 
                squareColor = 'white'
       
                penMain.fillcolor(squareColor)  
                penMain.begin_fill() 
                turtleBoard()  
                penMain.end_fill()
```

I believe this code works besides my one error! Thank you all for your help in advance!

Comment: Most of your code is in the function `turtleBoard()`, that you never call.  If you did call it manually, it would hang forever since it contains a recursive call to itself near the end.  I think those last four lines should not be indented at all.

Comment: that fixed the first issue, but now it just draws one black square and exits

Comment: The only part of `turtleBoard()` that actually draws anything is the first three lines.  The rest just moves the pen around without making any marks.

Comment: hmm ok I understand the theory of it. However it was working before so I'm lost as to what I  did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we've seen that your code can be made to work, let's consider *stamping* instead of *drawing* to make it work more simply and more quickly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SQUARES_PER_EDGE = 8
SQUARE_SIZE = 30  # in pixels
OFFSET = SQUARE_SIZE * (SQUARES_PER_EDGE / 2) - SQUARE_SIZE/2  # center the board

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def turtleBoard():
    turtle.shape('square')
    turtle.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.penup()

    for y in range(SQUARES_PER_EDGE):
        for x in range(SQUARES_PER_EDGE):
            turtle.goto(x * SQUARE_SIZE - OFFSET, y * SQUARE_SIZE - OFFSET)
            turtle.fillcolor('black' if y % 2 == x % 2 else 'white')
            turtle.stamp()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

turtleBoard()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say what changes you made to get your current code, but this code seems to be working:

```
##This program draws a checkboard using the turtle library
import turtle  

#below initiates the turtle pen and screen
penMain = turtle.Turtle()   
turtleMain = turtle.Screen() 
   
def turtleBoard(): 
    
    penMain.forward(30)  
    turtleMain.setup(600, 600) 
    penMain.speed(50) 
        
    for a in range(8): 
        for x in range(8): 
            penMain.up()  
            penMain.setpos(30 * x, 30 * a) 
            penMain.down() 
            penMain.begin_fill() 
            for xx in range(4): 
                penMain.forward(30) 
                penMain.left(90) 
            if a%2 == x%2: 
                squareColor = 'black'
            else: 
                squareColor = 'white'
       
            penMain.fillcolor(squareColor)  
            penMain.end_fill() 
            
turtleBoard()  
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

I lined  up the indent of the bottom 4 lines with the last 'else' statement and it worked. Thank you guys!